# What are "&" and "|" used for in this color generation code?

Tags: java, colors, 2d-games

Just stumbled upon the 2d game development video series on YouTube by designsbyzephy, and decided learning and understanding the code from the video will be my next Java learning venture.

The biggest obstacle is trying to decipher the code myself because the video maker has an incredibly newbie unfriendly approach to explaining everything.

So here's my question and the video

video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7eotyB7oNHE

at 5:31, he types in the code

```
int index = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++){
        for (int g = 0; g < 6; g++){
            for (int b = 0; b < 6; b++){

                int rr = (r * 255/5);
                int gg = (g * 255/5);
                int bb = (b * 255/5);

                colors[index++] = rr << 16 | gg << 8 | bb;
            }
        }
    }
colors[index++] = rr << 16 | gg << 8 | bb;
```

From my understanding he's filling the array with all combinations created by 6 shades for each color, but what I don't get is what the `|` symbol stands for. He mentions in the video that he talks about it in the previous videos, but he doesn't, I checked, and I am sure he's mistaking his explanation on `&` with `|`, because he does touch upon the `&` operation a little way, but never mentions `|` in any of his previous videos. Another thing I don't get is why we're shifting the colors. He explains it in the video, but it still doesn't make sense to me. Basically all he says is we shift it because `bb`, `gg`, and `rr` all have 2&8 bits of data in it, but that doesn't suffice as an explanation for me. I need to know why we're doing it, why do we need to shift to left just because the `bb`, `gg`, `rr` colors have 2^8 bits of data in it, and what does having 2^8 bits of data mean in the first place?

Comment: Too many questions. But there is an explanation of bitwise (`|`) operators here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: Really, most video tutorials on programming kinda suck. Actually, I take that back - most online tutorials in general kinda suck. It's not even necessarily because the authors themselves are bad at programming (although that's sometimes the case too), but often they're just really bad at explaining things and end up reading out their code loud. Sometimes the 'tutorial' in question could literally be summed up as `git clone some-repo`.

Comment: Yeah, so it's incredibly frustrating learning from videos, but I don't know of any other way I can learn 2d game programming. I have used online tutorials like zetcode and read books on the topic but most of them seem really dated and use bad programming practice. So I am pretty much in a dilemma. Do I need to go to school to learn game programming?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `|` in java is the bitwise or operator: [Bitwise operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR)
Without watching the whole video, I guess what he is trying to do is put
all color values (RGB) into one 32Bit integer. Since rr,gg,bb can only have values
from 0-255, which only need 8bits, he can put them into just one variable by using shift and or operations. For example:

```
rr:       00000000 00000000 00000000 10101010
rr<<16:   00000000 10101010 00000000 00000000

gg:       00000000 00000000 00000000 11110000
gg<<8:    00000000 00000000 11110000 00000000

bb:       00000000 00000000 00000000 00001111

value = rr << 16 | gg << 8 | bb 

rr<<16:   00000000 10101010 00000000 00000000
gg<<8:    00000000 00000000 11110000 00000000
bb:       00000000 00000000 00000000 00001111

value:    00000000 10101010 11110000 00001111
                      ^        ^        ^
                      rr       gg       bb
```

So now we have all three color values in one single integer variable.

Comment: I love you man, didn't know it was that simple. Wish I could rep but I need 15 reps

Comment: @GayLord: You've got 16 rep now after I've 1+ you and Hector. You will want to 1+ Hector and also click on the large green check outline next to his answer to "accept" it.

Comment: Thanks, I upped his comment and checked the green check.